# retrieving child records in Backbone/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Rails app with a Province.rb model that has a has_many relationship with the City.rb model. In the show action of the Province controller, I do this

```
@province= @province.cities
render json: @province, root: false
```

to be able to get the cities from the province when I render. That's easy to do with Rails, but I'm working with JSON data in Backbone. When I render a province object in Backbone, it doesn't have the cities available in it

```
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
id: 14
name: "Ontario"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c501"
collection: child
id: 14
__proto__: Surrogate
```

Question 1. Is there a way to make the cities available in the province object? so that I can call province.cities in javascript?

Not being able to access cities through a province object, I tried to query for cities based on the province id in the `showProvince` method in the router like this

```
  self.provinces = app.collections.provinces.get(id); 
  self.cities = app.collections.cities.where({province_id: id}).fetch() //doesn't work
```

But I can't call fetch after specifying `where`. Also, if I left off fetch, and tried it this way, I wasn't able to use a success callback on `where` method, and therefore, `self.cities` was undefined in the console.log because the code had moved on before the query had finished.

```
  self.cities = app.collections.cities.where({province_id: id}, {
                success: function(){
                      no success callback, how to process data

                }
            });
 console.log(self.cities)//undefined
```

Question 2: how to query a has_many association using the parent id?

Assuming I was able to retrieve the city records corresponding to the province, I'm not sure how to insert the two together into a few

```
this.showView( '#main', new app.Views.ProvinceView({model:self.province}) );
```

How would I include the cities for that province if I were able to retrieve them? Should I try to merge them with the province, or can they be included another way?

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm using Active Model Serializer, I had to declare the relation in the serializer and then the children cities were available on the Province object

```
class ProvinceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name

  has_many :cities
end
```

No need to try to do any of this

```
self.cities = app.collections.cities.where({province_id: id}).fetch() //doesn't work
```